# INFO Format reference from (boost property tree)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm searching for a way to write complex data configurations for my application. 
I don't really like xml or json for that job for different reasons.

But I found a format that is kind of perfect for the job, it's implemented in boost property tree library and is referenced as "INFO" format(

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.info_parser

).

The problem is I can't find a proper format description/reference because of the same named "info" file format for text info. 
Can some one share a link to a proper documentation or at least more exaples?

Comment: As the "INFO" format was designed only for the boost library, you may ask at the boost mailing list.

@karlphillip are you only answering for points?

Comment: Thomas thanks, I thought that it's a standard format of some kind...

Comment: @racer - this is by no means a standard.  Boost docs say : "The INFO format was created specifically for the property tree library."

Comment: @Thomas I reserve myself the right to NOT answer someone when I see he's not doing his share to contribute to the forum. It's fine when someone creates an account to only ask questions and get help. I see no problem with that. But it bothers me when that person doesn't do it's share. The least I expect from someone like that is to learn how we work and help keep the site organized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look at the [Boost docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.info_parser) on this?  I doubt there's a better reference.  As noted in the doc:

> It provides a simple, efficient format
>   that can be used to serialize property
>   trees that are otherwise only stored
>   in memory. It can also be used for any
>   other purpose, although **the lack of
>   widespread existing use may prove to
>   be an impediment**.

Generally I bemoan the overuse of XML but in this case, going that route (XML) is just as functional and a lot less controversial.  You get third-party parsing, transform (XSLT) and editing tools that you won't have with INFO.

Comment: The main idea is that this config should be written and read very easy by humans not necessary used to config files, and info format allows to design a very human readable data structure to configure a graph relation. JSON would be perfect if it didn't require to wrap the keys into "".

Comment: That's interesting - one of the main arguments that results in XML overuse is that it is human-readable.  I think given a freeware XML editor, XML would be a lot simpler for you but that's just an opnion.

Comment: XML is actually developer readable, and when you have to write a config on a remote server using a terminal and there is not even emacs or vi installed that it's becomes readable but not really writable. What I need is to have a very easy to grasp and write configs that do not require special tools, if anybody knows some think like this please share

Answer (score 0):

Look at  Boost's  property_tree/examples/info_grammar_spirit.cpp.

> /* This is grammar of INFO file format written in form of
>   boost::spirit rules.    For simplicity, it does not parse #include
>   directive. Note that INFO parser     included in property_tree library
>   does not use Spirit.
>   */